# PySpark - Salting an inner join in the presence of skew

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, saltedhash

I am using an inner join to generate record comparisons, for the purpose of [deduplicating data](https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/splink/blob/4a1704a3bf29703a90f19606989c8a6f8c25ec71/splink/blocking.py#L142).

I would like to salt these joins so that record comparisons are more equally distributed in the presence of skew.

What follows is a very simple motivating example - the real input data is much larger.

Suppose we have a table as follows (csv [here](https://gist.github.com/RobinL/e34dee0e06f982e9b43a43ce90ab2652)).

| first_name | surname | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| charles | dickens | london |
| charlie | dickens | london |
| virginia | woolf | london |
| virginia | wolf | london |
| mary | shelley | london |
| jane | austen | steventon |

To generate record comparisons I can write sql like:

```py
df = spark.read.csv()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

sql = """
select 
  l.first_name as first_name_l,
  r.first_name as first_name_r,
  l.surname as surname_l, 
  r.surname as surname_r,
  l.city as city_l,
  r.city as city_r
from df as l
inner join df as r
on l.city = r.city
"""
spark.sql(sql)
```

On a large dataset, spark will chose a `SortMergeJoin`.  The data will be HashPartitioned on `city`.

All 5 records with `city = london` will therefore end up on a single executor, on which the cartesian product of the `london` records will be produced - 25 records in total.

This creates a problem on real datasets where the count of `city=london` may be 10,000 - generating 100,000,000 comparisons in a single task on a single executor.

My question is **how can I salt this join to split up the work more evenly?**. Note that all 25 (or 100m) record comparisons need to be generated - it's just we want them to be spit between different tasks

### Solutions I've attempted

I have a working solution that's very inelegant, as follows.  I'm looking to improve on this.

Step 1:
Create a random integer column, `random_int`.  For simplicity, let's say this contains integers in the range 1-3.

Step 2:
Run the left join three times, and union all

```
select {cols}
from df as l
inner join df as r
on l.city = r.city and l.random_int = 1

UNION ALL

select {cols}
from df as l
inner join df as r
on l.city = r.city and l.random_int = 2

UNION ALL

select {cols}
from df as l
inner join df as r
on l.city = r.city and l.random_int = 3
```

This solution gives the right answer, and does run faster on large datasets in the presence of skew.  But it creates a lot of complexity on the execution plan, and I can't help feeling there must be a better way.

This real context problem is the blocking step of my open source software, [Splink](https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/splink).  So any help provided will help improve this software.  (PRs are of course welcome as well!)

Comment: Perhaps this is exactly what [Adaptive Query Execution](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/29/adaptive-query-execution-speeding-up-spark-sql-at-runtime.html) does.  I'm not sure it's a complete solution, though, because I don't think AQE anticipates that n-squared records will be generated within each join key.  It seems more for the case where one table has a key repeated 10m times, which needs to be joined to a lookup table